# How to apply a window function over a subset of rows inside dplyr::mutate?

Tags: r, filter, window-functions, dplyr

Let's imagine `mtcars` is an ordered data.frame and that I want the maximum over the previous rows. Then, I can do:

```
> mtcars %>% mutate(test = cummax(wt))
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  test
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2.620
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2.875
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 2.875
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 3.215
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 3.440
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 3.460
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 3.570
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 3.570
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 3.570
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 3.570
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 3.570
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 4.070
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 4.070
14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 4.070
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 5.250
16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 5.424
17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 5.424
...
```

Now I want to get the maximum, not just over all the previous rows, but only over the previous rows where `wt < 4`, so I would get a different result (represented below in the `test2` column) from row 12 for `test2` if the next instruction worked:

```
> mtcars %>% mutate(test = cummax(wt), test2 = cummax(wt[wt < 4]))
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  test test2
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2.620 2.620
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2.875 2.875
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 2.875 2.875
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 3.215 3.215
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 3.440 3.440
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 3.460 3.460
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 3.570 3.570
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 3.570 3.570
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 3.570 3.570
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 3.570 3.570
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 3.570 3.570
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 4.070 3.570
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 4.070 3.730
14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 4.070 3.780
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 5.250 3.780
16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 5.424 3.780
17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 5.424 3.780
...
```

But actually, that instruction produces an error:

```
> mtcars %>% mutate(test = cummax(wt[wt<4]))
Error: Column `test` must be length 32 (the number of rows) or one, not 28
```

And let me add that I would like do this by group, so the instruction would start by `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% ...`

How can I do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `ifelse`, and replace anything that violates your condition with `-Inf`

```
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(test = cummax(ifelse(wt < 4, wt, -Inf)))
```